# Nokia HERE sdk - How to orient map?

Tags: android, ios, here-api

In GoogleMaps if you want to change the orientation of the map you change the bearing of the 'camera' being used as perspective of the map.

How do I re-orient a Nokia HERE sdk map?
In other words, by default the map is displayed with North at the top.
But as the user moves, turns, drives etc., I want to reorient the map to match their course/heading/bearing/direction so that 'forward' is at the top.

I can get the direction the mobile device is facing from the built-in compass sensor without a problem.  I just can't find a method or parameter on the map object to set.

Answer (score 0):

The map can be orientated in any direction. By default, the orientation is in a true North position. The following code changes the orientation to South-up:

```
// Rotate 180 degrees.
map.setOrientation(180);

// Get the orientation, should be 180.
float orientation = map.getOrientation();
```

Source: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps.html

Comment: also great feature, if you driving among some route, each maneuver has its mapOrientation parameter, so you can smoothly animate your camera.