# Integrating HERE sdk into android app

Tags: android, here-api

I started developing an app using HERE api. Basically I have to navigate from one point to another using HERE sdk offline as well as online. Also I have to be able to rotate the map according to orientation of the mobile as we navigate, while showing the remaining distance to be covered in real-time. Next, I have to integrate a compass with the HERE map so compass tells the direction in which user is moving.

Answer (score 1):

Here are full working Android projects for all of your tasks using the HERE MobileSDK for Android:

1. Basic Map application: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/BasicMapSolutionGradle.zip
2. Positioning, Routing and turn by turn voice guidance:
   https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/TtsAndNavigation.zip
3. Compass and custom position marker rotating to compass north:
   https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip

Comment: thanks,in compass one,android studio is unable to find import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.LocalMesh;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapLocalModel;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapOverlayType;
Although i have added the sdk as shown on Here start guide.
Also what would be passed in parameters in this  m_PositionMarker = new MapCircle();

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is possible with the **Premium SDK** variant of the HERE Mobile SDK as offline support is not available in the **Starter SDK**.

However, integrating a compass is possible using the Starter edition: You can use the CustomPositionMarker example (https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip) with a few modifications since it was build for Premium SDK:

- Remove `LocalMesh`, `MapLocalModel`, `MapOverlayType` since these are suitable only for 3D Vector Maps which are not available in starter edition.
- Rotate the map according to current yaw like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290807/nokia-here-sdk-how-to-orient-map?rq=1). Place this code inside the `onSensorChanged()`-callback of Android's `SensorEventListener` (as shown by the example). This will rotate the map according to the sensor's azimuth.
- To render a compass needle or just a map center circle use for example HERE's 
  `MapCircle (double radius, GeoCoordinate center)`. Note that the constructor takes different arguments in the starter edition of the SDK.